# Powershell calling a script in a new job

Tags: powershell, start-job

i am trying to create a new job which calls a script:

```
Write-Output "start"

$j1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "Thread1 running"; & ${PSScriptRoot}\script.ps1 -ARG1 ${arg1} -ARG2 ${arg2}; Write-Output "Thread1 finish" }

$j1 | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

Write-Output "done"
```

But its not working.
The error says (german): `Die Benennung "\script.ps1" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.`

The problem is obviously in `& ${PSScriptRoot}\script.ps1 -ARG1 ${arg1} -ARG2 ${arg2};` but the root path is 100% correct.

Does somebody has a Solution for my problem?

Comment: Could you please hardcode the script path and execute it. As per the error, it is telling that the script path is wrong. So, why not hardcode the path and check once.

Comment: @RanadipDutta Yes, Thank you. Now the script gets called. I have a new error from the script.ps1 file but i think the job is working now

Comment: @RanadipDutta but why is that the case? its the same...

Comment: I am pretty much sure your path variable has issues. `${PSScriptRoot}` - You have not mentioned anything about the path variable that you have defined. Until and unless I see the path, it is tough to say.

Comment: @RanadipDutta ```$PSScriptRoot = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop".```
And then for testing I hardcoded it to ```& C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\script.ps1 -ARG1 ${arg1} -ARG2 ${arg2};```

Comment: Ah there you go. So $psscriptRoot\script.ps1 has to be string concatenated which is not there in your case. As a result, PS could not understand it and it was considering the path as `C:\Users\xxx\Desktopscript.ps1` instead of 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\script.ps1'. Kindly enclose that in the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

So `$psscriptRoot\script.ps1` has to be string concatenated which is not there in your case. As a result, PS could not understand it and it was considering the path as `C:\Users\xxx\Desktopscript.ps1` instead of `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\script.ps1`. Kindly enclose that in the double quotes:

Replace: `${PSScriptRoot}\script.ps1` with `"${PSScriptRoot}\script.ps1"`

Here is the output:

[image]

You should be good with the changes. Note by, that I have not worked on the argument part.